# Getting data out of array column in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I save my order data to `notifications` table as my notification `using laravel Notification` and I have problem with returning my data.

here is my notification method: `App\Notifications\OrderSubmited.php`

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'order_id' => $this->order->id,
            'title' => $this->order->title,
            'buyer' => $this->order->user_id,
            'status' => $this->order->orderstatus_id,
        ];
    }
```

My method to get data:

```
View::composer('admin.dashboard', function ($view) {
          $notifications = DB::table('notifications')->orderby('id', 'desc')
              ->latest()
              ->take(5)
              ->get();
          $notifs = $notifications;
          $view->with('notifs', $notifs);
        });
```

here is my blade code:

```
@foreach($notifs as $notif)

  {{dd($notif)}}

  @foreach($notif->data as $data)
    {{$data['order_id']}} <br>           
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

this is my `{{dd($notif)}}` output:

```
{#721 ▼
  +"id": "46546547464415474884"
  +"type": "App\Notifications\OrderSubmited"
  +"notifiable_id": 2
  +"notifiable_type": "App\Order"
  +"data": "{"order_id":2,"title":"tsdfg", "user_id":"1", "orderstatus_id":"11"}"
  +"read_at": null
  +"created_at": "2018-01-18 00:00:00"
  +"updated_at": "2018-01-18 00:00:00"
}
```

- as you can see data i try to return are stored in `data` column.

If I remove my `dd` i will get this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

On this line:

```
@foreach($notif->data as $data)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each notification is an object containing an array called `data` containing the values you return from your `toArray` method when creating the notification. You would normally iterate through your notifications and access their data like so:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {{ $notification->data['order_id'] }}
@endforeach
```

Laravel converts the `data` property (which is stored in the database as JSON) into an array.

However because you are retrieving the notifications yourself from the database without making use of the built in methods you will need to convert that data to an array from JSON yourself, like so:

```
View::composer('admin.dashboard', function ($view) {
    $notifications = DB::table('notifications')->orderby('id', 'desc')
      ->latest()
      ->take(5)
      ->get();

    $view->with('notifications', $notifications);
});
```

Then from within your view:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    @php $data = json_decode($notification->data, true); @endphp
    {{ $data['order_id'] }}
@endforeach
```

---

Regarding your follow up question, something like this:

```
View::composer('admin.dashboard', function ($view) {
    $notifications = DB::table('notifications')->orderby('id', 'desc')
      ->latest()
      ->take(5)
      ->get()
      ->map(function ($item, $key) {
          $item->data = json_decode($item->data);
          $item->data->user = User::find($item->data->user_id);
          return $item;
      });

    $view->with('notifications', $notifications);
});
```

Then from within your view:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {{ $notification->data->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: `Illegal string offset 'order_id' `

Comment: @mafortis sorry about that, I hit enter too early, check my answer now :-)

Comment: still says `Illegal string offset 'order_id'` do i have to add anything in my notificationb model? however when you use `laravel notifications` there will be no model (no need to that!) but if necessary i make for it? i mean to make something like `casts` etc.?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer, please try again: it should be `{{ $data['order_id'] }}` not `{{ $notification->data['order_id'] }}`

Comment: ok, its working but there 2 things need to be fixed here. 1- i want to move `@php $data = json_decode($notif->data, true); @endphp` in my `composer view` instead of being in blade  2- i want to get info out of `id's` such as `user_id` i want get user `name` out of it. how to do that?

Comment: You can use the [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) method on your collection to decode the json in your view composer. You can use the same approach for injecting the relationship models. I have updated the answer for you -- keep in mind, I switched from using an array to an object.

Comment: thanks dude it's working for user but user was only sample because as you see in my dd i also have `orderstatus_id`. it there a way to get both of them the way you get user name?

Comment: Yes, simply add an extra assignment in the map, e.g: `$item->data->orderstatus = OrderStatus::find($item->data->orderstatus_id);` and `$item->data->order = Order::find($item->data->order_id);` then you can access both as `{{ $notification->data->orderstatus->property }}` and `{{ $notification->data->order->property }}`